# How to shuffle data in google sheets after x number of seconds?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm working on a google sheet and i need to shuffle my records after every x number of seconds, what i'm doing is selecting whole data and then goto `Data > Randomize Data` to randomize it.

What i need is to randomize automatically after every x seconds. What should be done to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. In your situation, you want to randomize the selected cells? Or you want to randomize all values in the active sheet? 2. In the current stage, the maximum execution time of Google Apps Script is 6 minutes. So if you want to run the script more than this time, I think that it is required to use Javascript at the sidebar and dialog. How about this?

Comment: 1. all values in sheet 1 for example. 
2. yes i want to run this 24 x 7 without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to randomize the range on Google Spreadsheet by giving the specific interval.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following 2 sample scripts.

### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, only Google Apps Script is used. As a test case, before you run the script, please set a checkbox to a cell "A1". In this script, when the checkbox is checked after the script is run, the script is stopped.

As an important point, in the current stage, the maximum execution time of Google Apps Script is 6 minutes. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) Please be careful this.

#### Script:

```
function sample1() {
  const interval = 2; // 2 seconds. Please set here.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A1").uncheck();
  while (true) {
    sheet.getActiveRange().randomize(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:C10").randomize();
    Utilities.sleep(interval * 1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    if (sheet.getRange("A1").isChecked()) {
      ss.toast("end");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample script 2:

In the current stage, the maximum execution time of Google Apps Script is 6 minutes. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) So, if you want to run the script more than this time, I would like to propose to use Javascript at the sidebar and dialog.

Please copy and paste the following scripts to the script editor.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please run `openSidebar`. By this, the sidebar is opened on the Spreadsheet. And, when you click "start" button, the active range is randomize by `interval`. When "end" button is clicked, the script is stopped.

```
function openSidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function randomizeRange() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().randomize();
}
```

- For example, when you want to randomize the specific range, you can also use the following script. In this case, "A1:C10" is randomized.

  ```
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:C10").randomize();
  ```

#### HTML & Javascript side: `index.html`

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()">

<script>
const interval = 2; // 2 seconds. Please set here.
let r;

const worker = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withFailureHandler(e => reject(e)).withSuccessHandler(e => resolve(e)).randomizeRange());

function start() {
  r = setInterval(async () => await worker(), interval * 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(r);
}
</script>
```

### References:

- [randomize()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#randomize())
- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)